# TV series from 70s or 80s - 1 female pilot was cloned from the other pilot's fingernail

Tags: story-identification, tv, clones

This was a tv show that aired in the US in the '70s or early '80s, possibly on Saturday mornings. Since I was a child, I'm assuming it was a kids program? It was comic science fiction and set on a spaceship. The only 3 specific details I remember are:

1. The crew traveled between ship levels by using open "jump tubes" that were similar to a giant vacuum tube message system, only without any "container" for the passenger. They just stepped into an alcove with a big hole in the floor and ceiling, then shot up or down. Frequently the show would use this as a source of slap-stick comedy.
2. The captain was male.
3. The 2 pilots were female, and 1 had been cloned from the other's fingernail cell. They often disagreed about which one was the clone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(TV_series)) (1977)?

This TV series was a spoof of sci-fi movies and shows, it took place on a spaceship and had two clone women who were always arguing about which one was the clone and which was the original. It lasted one season.

Full episodes can be viewed on YouTube, there were 8 in all. Here is one titled "Goodbye Polumbus". You can see the clones speaking at 00:42 and the "jump tubes" at 12:50.

Comment: Any jump tubes?

Comment: @Valorum. Yes, they had some kind of tubes, but they also had a kind of transporter similar to the ones in Star Trek TOS.

Comment: The jump tubes are being used at 12:50 in this video.

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister. I've never seen this show but knew about it. I'm going to start watching it now, they look very funny.

Comment: Wow, Tim Thomerson looks like a kid here!

Comment: FWIW the full series (what there was) DVD is available on Netflix

Answer (score 3):

Could this be "[Space Cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Cases)"?

[This review](https://retrorewatchblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/06/space-cases-tie-me-kangaroo-down-court/) mentions the crew traveling via

> jump tubes

and the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Cases) mentions cloning confusion.

> Because of its cancellation, the series has no true ending, and leaves
>   several storylines open. One such storyline comes about in the episode
>   "Trouble With Doubles," in which the crew becomes cloned and must each
>   battle their own evil selves. At the end of the episode, it is
>   explained that Goddard has been cloned before. When asked what
>   assurances the crew has that he isn't a clone of the real Goddard, the
>   episode ends in ambivalence, with no true answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

*Space Cases* ran from 1996-1997.  *Quark* ran on and off from May 1977 to April 1978 and thus fits  the time period better.  It was a live action comedy like *Space Cases*.

1. I don't remember if there  is tube travel in the ship.
2. Adam Quark is the male commander.
3. Betty I & Betty II are the identical pilot and navigator of the ship.  They disagree which one is the clone of the other one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(TV_series)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(TV_series))

Thus you have the not so bad problem of having to investigate two good shows to find which is the one you remember.

Comment: This appears to be a comment rather than an actual answer.